# Is it true, that Trump sanctions as of 01.06.2019 have started battery drainage on Huawei Android mobile phones?

Tags: updates, battery, huawei

It is 1st of June 2019 and new round of sanctions have started under Trump. And severe drainage of battery of my Huawei Android phone has started as well. 20% of batter is gone under just 1 hour. Android System is the main user of battery - around 30%, then WhatsApp follow with 23%. Remaining apps consume less. I have pending update from Android 5.x to Android 6.x on my device but there is button to download this update and I have choosen not to do any activity. Why such unexpected drainage. Is it due to Trump?

p.s. and my Grindr application is ceased to start as well. Who knows what else will happen?

Comment: It's a google phone, everything is possible.. but funny question anyway. I guess it is related more to google play services, they sometimes release worse updates (and you can not prevent Google Play from updating itself)

Comment: Well, if Trump says "Huawei is shit", your phone might start to stink. That's what he calls "laws of physics" (or something like that). // Honestly: Why should the two be related? Asking whether it's true (no, that's bullshit): has that indeed been stated in some "fake news", and if so where?

Comment: https://kojenov.com/2020-09-15-hisilicon-encoder-vulnerabilities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it not because of Trump. Why? Because Huawei was granted 90 days during which it will still continue to support equipment.

> The Trump administration is working to ban Huawei products from the US market and ban US companies from supplying the Chinese company with software and components. The move will have wide-ranging consequences for Huawei's smartphone, laptop, and telecom-equipment businesses. For the next 90 days, though, Huawei will be allowed to support those products. The US Department of Commerce (DOC) has granted temporary general export license for 90 days, so while the company is still banned from doing business with most US companies, it is allowed to continue critical product support.

Even if it was not granted an extension period, I don't see how suddenly the battery will start draining.

By the way, Huawei and Google are still working together on security issues during the 90-day exemption

> The 90-day license means Google can work with Huawei again on smartphone updates. A Google spokesperson told CNBC, "Keeping phones up to date and secure is in everyone's best interests, and this temporary license allows us to continue to provide software updates and security patches to existing models for the next 90 days."

From the second listed source:

> Existing owners of Huawei smartphones can continue to enjoy Google apps and services, such as Google Maps, Gmail and YouTube. They can still use the Google Play Store and receive security and software updates for Google apps and services.

> Existing Huawei smartphones, like the recent Huawei P30 Pro, will continue to have access to Google apps and services, as well as security updates. But Huawei may not be able to update the Android software to the next version promptly, if at all.
>
> Since most Android smartphone makers, such as Samsung, take months to update the Android software with the latest features, consumers may not be overly concerned about this.

In mid August, if the exemption is not renewed, your battery will still work fine (assuming it is not old or damaged already).

Check your running services and processes to find out what is causing the battery to drain.

You question will be great at Skeptics StackExchange.

Source:

1. [The US DOC gives Huawei a 90-day window to support existing devices](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2019/05/google-and-huawei-can-support-devices-for-90-days-thanks-to-us-ban-exemption/)
2. [Huawei barred from Google updates: What you need to know if you own a Huawei or Honor phone](https://www.straitstimes.com/tech/huawei-banned-from-google-updates-what-you-need-to-know-about-the-ban)

Answer (score 1):

I have Huawei P9, been going grand for a few years, I kept it on old Android version, heavy ish use though loads of apps installed battery would last a day, less if I had maps/gps route tracking.

Tuesday this week 25/6/2019 quite inconveniently big battery drain started happening. Google Play Services listed as top user along with Android OS. I did a big cleanup, got rid of some big apps, got rid of an unused account, tightened up on apps, upgraded OS.

Then finally **disabled automatic app updates.**
This seemed to stop the battery drain!

The OS upgrade has changed look/feel but has made phone have faster response which is also a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

This is just political nonsense. Awaiting the day rest of world is bleeding out of rare earth minerals now, china has the monopol..  good by apple, hello huawei :D Check your background data usage, then you will know who is leading the war of data gathering. Delete Instagram Facebook and WhatsApp, this will really save your battery (and privacy)